# How to store file in a browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am working for a prototype of website(Only Browser based). There is a part where I need to upload some files.Here I am using JavaScript and HTML.

Whenever user wants to upload(Like Browse button in applications) some files then it will available for next time.I am unable to do this.

**Question** Can we save/store/upload a file using JavaScript/HTML in browser only(Not server )??

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible to write files client-side only... you can read them via [HTML5's File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), but writing them would probably cause way too many security issues

Comment: Is next time on the same machine only?

Comment: yes on the same machine. Is it possible. @ Michael Durrant

Answer (score 8):

### Downloading file directly to user's file-system

If you by save/store mean directly to user's computer/file system then no, this is not possible due to security reasons.

However, you can *initiate* a download which will pop up a "save as" type of requester and allow user to accept or deny to download the file.

There are more than one way to initiate a download. An interesting one is the new `download` [attribute](http://caniuse.com/download) for the anchor tag where you can specify a file name as well as automatically initiate the download setting its `href` to a [data-uri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) or something else you want to reference for download:

```
<a href="urlToFile" download="myFile.ext">Click to download</a>
```

### Local storage mechanisms

If you simply want to save the file *locally* you can use one of the many local storage mechanisms such as:

- [File system API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/) (only supported in [Chrome currently and the new Opera](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem). In draft status)
- [Indexed DB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) (allows Blob objects. [Good support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb))
- [Web SQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) (deprecated but [widely in use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage))
- [Web Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) ([very good support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage) but only stores strings and has limited space, objects can be saved as JSON strings)

Note that all of these as sand-boxed and only available in the browser using the same [origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) as they was written from. The data may or may not be discarded at any point as well (by user or by browser) so they are not a "safe" storage (always keep a server copy or a way to regenerate the data).

Comment: for images which approach is best??

Comment: @ShyamDixit I would "recommend" File API but as it is in development and only supported by Chrome I would say Indexed DB as this allows Blob and you can request quota.

Comment: Please note that the statuses of each of the technologies are quite out of date, for example, the File System API is no longer being maintained.

Comment: @Harvey it seems like at least index DB's [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) has been updated in 2018.  Others indeed haven't been updated for 4+ years (or even 10 for Web SQL).  So now in 2020, what are the recommended ways to store data on client side (browser)?  It would be great if you can share as answer to this thread to make this post more updated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible via [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) (currently [only Chrome and Opera](http://caniuse.com/#search=filesystem)).

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').onchange = function(e) {
  var files = this.files;

  window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, function(fs) {
    // Duplicate each file the user selected to the app's fs.
    for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; ++i) {

      // Capture current iteration's file in local scope for the getFile() callback.
      (function(f) {
        fs.root.getFile(f.name, {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(fileEntry) {
          fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
            fileWriter.write(f); // Note: write() can take a File or Blob object.
          }, errorHandler);
        }, errorHandler);
      })(file);

    }
  }, errorHandler);

};
```

Comment: "Whenever user wants to upload(Like Browse button in applications) some files then it `will available for next time.`"

Comment: The files written will be stored in a sandboxed directory and are available for any time.

Comment: great! i was unaware of that.+1 But it's `non standard` way as mentioned here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystem

Comment: You got the wrong link. FileSystem (not LocalFileSystem) is [yet-to-be standardised](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/).

Answer (score -3):

"Can we save/store/upload a file using JavaScript/HTML in browser only(Not server )??"

**Ans.** is **No**. If you want to retain the uploaded file then you need to store it on server.

The moment the browser tab is closed the file will get lost.

Alternative: What you can do is store the name of the file on server and whenever user request the file then ask him to upload it.

For uploading the file into memory you can refer to this **[link](http://codewithlogic.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/creating-a-file-uploader-using-javascript-and-html-5/)** .

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/enaqib/10)

Comment: Yes I am able to save the file name only not the whole path

Comment: @ShyamDixit Then ask the user to enter the path manually during first upload.