# Add downloadable file to another page with JavaScript in Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, python, html, csv, google-app-engine

I'm relatively new to Google App Engine and JavaScript, so I'm really not sure if I'm following good practice for this or anything, but here goes.

I have a game running on one page of my web application where I am collecting data on the user's movement and putting it in a csv file (i.e. I am creating a csv file in my JavaScript code). I have created a link that will automatically download the file on that specific page, but what I really want to do is add a link to download the file to a different page of my site. Is there any easy way to do this in JavaScript?

This is my current download code (where csvContent is a global variable with all the info I need in my csv)

```
//download csv file
function downloadData() {
    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "game1_data.csv");
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF
    link.click();
}
```

Ideally there would be a way to output the file to somewhere besides my current doc (like a different path on the website). For example, if I were on a page '/game', I'd want to create an element on '/files'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to store file for user locally and give option to download within your domain pages, you can use **fileSystem API** (supported by chrome and opera) or **Indexed db** (supported by most browsers) to store locally in browser.

Refer here - [How to store file in a browser using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294731/how-to-store-file-in-a-browser-using-javascript)

If you intend to save the file on server use google cloud storage[1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/). You get 5 gb storage and 1 bucket free with google cloud. This way user can view/download it anywhere.