# Store Uploaded CSV to Browser Storage

Tags: html, django, csv, local-storage, browser-cache

Any way we can store CSV file in Browser Storage and retrieve it later and process in the backend.

Issue:
I want to add Import Question Button to Django admin Form View. It works fine if the record is already saved.
In case of the new record, if csv file selected and some of the fields are not validated, then Django auto reload while saving the record and due to that selected csv is cleared.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294731/how-to-store-file-in-a-browser-using-javascript, though what you're describing seems like a "hacky" solution. What about client side validation? So you know pretty much for sure that the backend validation will pass? Or send the form in background using "ajax", and then handle the response (invalid fields or ok) on the client side, without reloading the whole page?

Comment: Client side validation and other validation is performed, but I want to perform only if whole dajngo forms validates.

Comment: Two options to achieve:
1. Either I can alter django admin form
2. Or store CSV file on browser and as when required uploaded and deleted